# Hibernate and padding on CHAR primary key column in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I'm having a little trouble using Hibernate with a char(6) column in Oracle. Here's the structure of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE ACCEPTANCE
(
   USER_ID char(6) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   ACCEPT_DATE date
);
```

For records whose user id has less than 6 characters, I can select them without padding the user id when running queries using SQuirreL. I.E. the following returns a record if there's a record with a user id of "abc".

```
select * from acceptance where user_id = "abc"
```

Unfortunately, when doing the select via Hibernate (JPA), the following returns null:

```
em.find(Acceptance.class, "abc");
```

If I pad the value though, it returns the correct record:

```
em.find(Acceptance.class, "abc   ");
```

The module that I'm working on gets the user id unpadded from other parts of the system. Is there a better way to get Hibernate working other than putting in code to adapt the user id to a certain length before giving it to Hibernate? (which could present maintenance issues down the road if the length ever changes)

Comment: "if the length ever changes". If that happens, your primary key changes and you've got a LOT more problems to worry about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's God's way of telling you to never use CHAR() for primary key :-)

Seriously, however, since your `user_id` is mapped as String in your entity Hibernate's Oracle dialect translates that into `varchar`. Since Hibernate uses prepared statements for all its queries, that semantics carries over (unlike SQuirreL, where the value is specified as literal and thus is converted differently).

Based on Oracle [type conversion rules](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements002.htm) column value is then promoted to `varchar2` and compared as such; thus you get back no records.

If you can't change the underlying column type, your best option is probably to use HQL query and `rtrim()` function which is supported by Oracle dialect.

Comment: I thought about doing something like em.createQuery("from Acceptance where trim(userId) = :userId"); but would that defeat the index on the primary key?

Comment: You only need `rtrim()`, not full `trim()` - and that should still use the index for non-whitespace characters.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I found some forum posts on Google which say that rtrim _does_ cause a table scan.

Comment: You can always create function-based index specifically for `rtrim()` if regular index doesn't get picked up.

Comment: I ended up putting in the effort to get the column changed to varchar2. I'm accepting this answer because I thought it was the most informative.

Comment: I would appreciate an example of how to rtrim() a column

Answer (score 1):

How come that your module gets an unpadded value from other parts of the system?

According to my understanding, if the other part of the system don't alter the PK, they should read 6 chars from the db and pass 6 chars all along the way -- that would be ok. The only exception would be when a PK is generated, in which case it may need to be padded.

You can circumvent the problem (by trimming or padding the value each time it's necessary), but it won't solve the problem upfront that your PK is not handled consistently. To solve the problem upfront you must eiher

- always receive 6 chars from the other parts of the module
- use `varchar2` to deal with dynamic size correctly

If you can't solve the problem upfront, then you will indeed need to either

- add trimming/padding all around the place when necessary
- add trimming/padding in the DAO if you have one
- add trimming/padding in the user type if this works (suggestion from N. Hughes)

Comment: I'd even say if the DB type is a CHAR(6) then it semantically expects customers for that DB to work with 6 chars, period. So either the DB definition has to be changed, or the customers need to comply :)